# Turning on MultiSampling results in no sprites being drawn

Tags: c#, monogame

In a MonoGame project, when I do this in the `Initialize()` method

```
graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
Console.WriteLine($"Device: {graphics.GraphicsDevice.Adapter.Description}");
Console.WriteLine($"Anti-aliasing: {(rasterizer.MultiSampleAntiAlias ? "YES" : "NO")}");
Console.WriteLine($"MultiSampling: {(graphics.PreferMultiSampling ? "YES" : "NO")}");
```

And this is in my `Draw` method

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
spriteBatch.Begin(rasterizerState: rasterizer);
DrawCheckerboard();
spriteBatch.End();
base.Draw(gameTime);
```

[image]

However, when `PreferMultiSampling = false`, the result is:

[image]

This was tested with a clean new project, the only thing I added is

```
RasterizerState rasterizer = new RasterizerState { MultiSampleAntiAlias = false };
```

For use with the SpriteBatch

```
spriteBatch.Begin(rasterizerState: rasterizer);
```

But adding/removing it doesn't have any impact.

The checkerboard is drawn using a single-pixel texture, upscaled.

```
pixel = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
pixel.SetData(new[] { Color.White });
```

And the process of drawing (probably unrelated to the cause of the issue) looks like this:

```
void DrawCheckerboard() {
    bool IsWhite(int x, int y) {
        var a = x % 2 == 0;
        var b = y % 2 == 0;
        return a == b;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            var coordinates = ScaleCheckerboardCoordinatesToScreen(new Point(x, y));
            spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(coordinates, new Point(squareSize)), IsWhite(x, y) ? Color.White : Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
Point ScaleCheckerboardCoordinatesToScreen(Point coordinates) {
    return new Point(offsetX + coordinates.X * squareSize, offsetY + coordinates.Y * squareSize);
}
```

Where could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've browsed a bit and I came accross [this site](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182725-How-to-resolve-integer-multisampled-texture-attached-to-a-framebuffer):

My guess that it happens is because you're changing the colors, and the multisampler can't handle that.

An idea is, instead of changing the colors, to use a black sprite and a white sprite instead. 
Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, it doesn't work. I tried `spriteBatch.Draw(IsWhite(x,y) ? whitePixel : blackPixel, new Rectangle(coordinates, new Point(squareSize)), Color.White);` and the behaviour is still the same (multisampling on -> sprites don't get drawn).